# AngularJS Forms, check validity

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I have a form and want to test the validity of the form. I have a function in the controller that checks for $valid

```
$scope.checkValid = function(){
    console.log($scope.form.address)
    console.log($scope.form.address.$valid);
    if($scope.form.address.$valid){ 
       dosomething();
     }
 }
```

The dosomething() does nothing!!
The first console.log produces a Constructor object with the valid as true.

```
$valid: true
```

yet the second console log displays FALSE!

Why would this happen? I cant figure it out and google has no answers.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: By "The dosomething() does nothing!!" you do mean "The dosomething() is never called!!" ?

Comment: could you create a jsfiddle for your problem

Comment: here is a basic jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xyorzghz/14/
As you can see in the html its true but in the controller it doesnt do the $scope.dosomething();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to validate form validity, and thats variable "formName.$valid" in form´s scope.

You really should provide jsfiddle as others mentioned, because you didnt specified, where and how are you using this method checkValid();

You can see any validation errors in "formName.$error"

**UPDATE on your fiddle:**

You didnt set any watcher on that validity variable

Repaired working fiddle is here: [Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/qbfk16ex/1/)

```
_
```

Or, you can use "ng-change='inputChanged(event)' " on that input and check validity there.

Comment: Apologies on that, I have one now in the above comments.

Comment: Thanks for the update. What I am trying to do though is evaluate the forms validity before the user inputs any information.

Comment: Thing is, that form is not loaded after controller starts, so you cannot get form in scope yet. But you can wrap check into timeout service, example: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pj0evpcv/)

Comment: This was the exact answer I was looking for. Thank you. It all works now.